# Do I need mongoose with graphql?

Tags: mongodb, graphql

If I want to connect a mongo database to graphql schema, do I need mongoose ORM or can I just do raw drivers calls?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do both.

If you have mongoose models already defined, you can use them while writing `resolve` functions. See the [following example](https://www.compose.io/articles/using-graphql-with-mongodb/).

```
var QueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({  
  name: 'Query',
  fields: () => ({
    todos: {
      type: new GraphQLList(TodoType),
      resolve: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          TODO.find((err, todos) => {
            if (err) reject(err)
            else resolve(todos)
          })
        })
      }
    }
  })
})
```

If you don't have mongoose models or if you want to use mongodb native driver, you can do that too. Following is a simple example of doing so using [MongoDB Node.JS Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native).

```
resolve: () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.collection('todos').find({}).toArray((err, todos) => {
      if (err) reject(err)
      else resolve(todos)
    })
  })
}
```

If you have mongoose models and you want to generate GraphQL schema from them, you may be interested in [graffiti-mongoose](https://github.com/RisingStack/graffiti-mongoose), which generates GraphQL types and schemas from existing mongoose models.

Comment: Mongoose retruns a promise if you don't pass a callback. You may simply return `TODO.find()` in the resolve function.